# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a TypeError, although my application is running properly.

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null"

Don't get how to resolve this. Could any one give me some idea or help me to understand why this is happening?
[image]

```js
if (isInitial) {
    // Add Data Rows (initially)
    for (const row of rows) {
        const clientVisitGuid = row[2];
        const location = row[3];
        row[5] = row[5].replace(/\//g, '\/\u200B');
        const service = row[5];
        const rowId = `${service || 'zzz'}_${location}_${clientVisitGuid}`;
        const sortString = `${service || 'zzz'}_${location}_${clientVisitGuid}`;
        const daysPastDischarge = parseInt(row[6]);
        const isMarked = parseInt(row[7]) === 1 ? true : false;
        if (cbt.hasBodyRow(rowId) === false) {
            const values: Array<[string, string | number]> = [];
            let isAllClear = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                const colId: string = cbt.headerRow.headerCols[i].id;
                const colVal: string | number = row[i];
                if (cbt.headerRow.headerCols[i].isFlag === true && colVal !== 1) {
                    isAllClear = false;
                }
                values.push([colId, colVal]);
            }
            const valueHash = hash(JSON.stringify(row));
            cbt.addBodyRow(
                rowId,
                values,
                valueHash,
                sortString,
                daysPastDischarge,
                isMarked,
                isAllClear,
                true,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know what "rows" is before we can help you.

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing what is contained in rows when this happens. I would assume row[5] at some point is null and thus throwing this error. You can update the code to check to see if the value is null before running the rest and then having it react in a way that makes sense for your use case (not executing the remainder of the code, supplying a default value, or just running the rest of the code with null but not attempting to replace characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix error you need to check if variable exists before trying to replace the string. Wrap it with an if statement like this:

```
if(row[5]) {
    row[5] = row[5].replace(/\//g, '\/\u200B');
    const service = row[5];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `row[5]` is null. You should first check if the `row[5]` exists. Something like

```
if(row[5]) {
     row[5] = row[5].replace(/\//g, '\/\u200B');
     const service = row[5];
}
```

You should also consider adding some handling event when the value is empty